# Where does Apache HTTP server stores incoming request's data

Tags: linux, apache

I have Apache HTTP server configured on Linux machine. I am sending requests to it from my Windows machine. I want to check the contents of incoming request. Where does it stores the data of incoming request? I think on Windows machine it uses **C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp** file for this. I have looked into **/var/tmp** folder on Linux machine but all files in that folder are empty.

I have a json web service developed using web2py framework and it is hosted on Apache HTTP server on Linux machine. It has get_tkn web service which I am trying to access from Python shell.

```
import jsonrpclib
import json

server_url = 'http://ip_address/appname/controllername/call/jsonrpc/'
api = jsonrpclib.Server(server_url)
tk_request = { 
                 'header' : { 
                                'a_id':u'f23ew343',\ 
                                'a_key':u'ldddk333k444d4',
                                'r_id':'12345',
                                't_id':'mec','uip_address':'someipaddr',
                                'tkn':''
                            },           
                 'body' : {'prms' :{}}
             }
api.get_tkn(tk_request)
```

Comment: Which server are you using?

Answer (score 3):

It logs all the incoming requests or any errors that occur. To view the log live in your Linux terminal use the following command

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts.access.log
```

The location and the name of the log file depends on your linux distribution. 
Under debian/ubuntu it is /var/log/apache2 and on centos/fedora it is /var/log/httpd folder. After the command above, send your requests from windows and view the live logs in your linux terminal.

Comment: In my case it is at /var/log/httpd/access_log. But it doesn't has the data of request. What I want is to see what data is coming in the request.

Comment: can you paste an example here? post or get parameters?

Comment: Then you have to use mod_status of the apache server. After installing and enabling it , restart apache with apachectl fullstatus command. It will need links package, if you are on a centos machine it is elinks package. Another way to see it listening the traffic with wireshark.

Answer (score 1):

**Linux**

**For Apache web server**

/var/log/apache2/access.log
**or**
"/var/log/httpd/access_log"

**Xampp on Windows**

\xampp\apache\logs\error.log

**OR else**

check with `phpinfo()`

Comment: In my case it is at /var/log/httpd/access_log. But it doesn't has the data of request. What I want is to see what data is coming in the request.